# Can't rename ... No such file or directory

Tags: linux, find, rename

I have some files need to rename recursively. So I execute the command `find shop-bill -depth -type f -exec rename -v "s/shop/shop-bill/" {} +`, but it gave me the following error. I was confused about the `No such file or directory` error and I can confirm that the files does exist.

```
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src$ find shop-bill -depth -type f -exec rename -v "s/shop/shop-bill/" {} +
Can't rename shop-bill/dto/shop.dto.ts shop-bill-bill/dto/shop.dto.ts: No such file or directory
Can't rename shop-bill/shop.controller.ts shop-bill-bill/shop.controller.ts: No such file or directory
Can't rename shop-bill/shop.entity.ts shop-bill-bill/shop.entity.ts: No such file or directory
Can't rename shop-bill/shop.module.ts shop-bill-bill/shop.module.ts: No such file or directory
Can't rename shop-bill/shop.providers.ts shop-bill-bill/shop.providers.ts: No such file or directory
Can't rename shop-bill/shop.service.ts shop-bill-bill/shop.service.ts: No such file or directory
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src$
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src$ ll shop-bill/dto/shop.dto.ts
-rwxrwxrwx 1 liudonghua liudonghua 879 May 29 17:17 shop-bill/dto/shop.dto.ts*
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src$ tree shop-bill
shop-bill
├── dto
│   └── shop.dto.ts
├── shop.controller.ts
├── shop.entity.ts
├── shop.module.ts
├── shop.providers.ts
└── shop.service.ts

1 directory, 6 files
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src$
```

The strange thing is that I can execute the similar command successfully like this.

```
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src$
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src$ tree operator-bill
operator-bill
├── dto
│   └── shop.dto.ts
├── shop.controller.ts
├── shop.entity.ts
├── shop.module.ts
├── shop.providers.ts
└── shop.service.ts

1 directory, 6 files
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src$ find operator-bill -depth -type f -exec rename -v "s/shop/operator-bill/" {} +
operator-bill/dto/shop.dto.ts renamed as operator-bill/dto/operator-bill.dto.ts
operator-bill/shop.controller.ts renamed as operator-bill/operator-bill.controller.ts
operator-bill/shop.entity.ts renamed as operator-bill/operator-bill.entity.ts
operator-bill/shop.module.ts renamed as operator-bill/operator-bill.module.ts
operator-bill/shop.providers.ts renamed as operator-bill/operator-bill.providers.ts
operator-bill/shop.service.ts renamed as operator-bill/operator-bill.service.ts
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src$
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src$ rename -v
Usage:
    rename [ -h|-m|-V ] [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] [ -e|-E perlexpr]*|perlexpr
    [ files ]

liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src$ rename -V
/usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 0.20

liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src$
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the problem, it was the parent directory also have renamed.

```
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src$ find shop-bill -depth -type f -exec rename -n "s/shop/shop-bill/" {} +
rename(shop-bill/dto/shop.dto.ts, shop-bill-bill/dto/shop.dto.ts)
rename(shop-bill/shop.controller.ts, shop-bill-bill/shop.controller.ts)
rename(shop-bill/shop.entity.ts, shop-bill-bill/shop.entity.ts)
rename(shop-bill/shop.module.ts, shop-bill-bill/shop.module.ts)
rename(shop-bill/shop.providers.ts, shop-bill-bill/shop.providers.ts)
rename(shop-bill/shop.service.ts, shop-bill-bill/shop.service.ts)
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src$ ll shop-bill-bill/dto/shop.dto.ts
ls: cannot access 'shop-bill-bill/dto/shop.dto.ts': No such file or directory
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src$
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src$ cd shop-bill
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src/shop-bill$
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src/shop-bill$ find . -depth -type f -exec rename -n "s/shop/shop-bill/" {} +
rename(./dto/shop.dto.ts, ./dto/shop-bill.dto.ts)
rename(./shop.controller.ts, ./shop-bill.controller.ts)
rename(./shop.entity.ts, ./shop-bill.entity.ts)
rename(./shop.module.ts, ./shop-bill.module.ts)
rename(./shop.providers.ts, ./shop-bill.providers.ts)
rename(./shop.service.ts, ./shop-bill.service.ts)
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src/shop-bill$ find . -depth -type f -exec rename -v "s/shop/shop-bill/" {} +
./dto/shop.dto.ts renamed as ./dto/shop-bill.dto.ts
./shop.controller.ts renamed as ./shop-bill.controller.ts
./shop.entity.ts renamed as ./shop-bill.entity.ts
./shop.module.ts renamed as ./shop-bill.module.ts
./shop.providers.ts renamed as ./shop-bill.providers.ts
./shop.service.ts renamed as ./shop-bill.service.ts
liudonghua@desktop-ldh:/mnt/d/code/node/nestjs-sequelize-typescript/src/shop-bill$
```